# DialogFragment containing a ListView with EditText- focus wont popup keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

Im having difficulty to understand the unique behavior I found.
I have a layout with only a ListView, where its item layout is some texts & editText.
Showing such a dialog onscreen leads to an unexpected behavior - keyboard wont pop-up when giving focus to it.
I strangely find that if I add another element to the dialog's layout, the issue is solved.

Dialog layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"

        />


    <!-- patch. otherwise, EditText within listview wont pop keyboard. weird, right? -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Item layout:

```
..
...
....
     <EditText
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:ems="5"
     android:maxEms="5"
     android:editable="true"
     android:numeric="integer"
     android:id="@+id/purchaseAmount" />
....
...
..
```

Can anyone give an explanation to that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the ListView does not have focus. You can ensure this by modifying your xml slightly.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView">
    <requestFocus/>
</ListView>
```